# Feature ranking for *known* clusters

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, feature-selection

I am aware of feature ranking (i.e. selecting the 'best' features) for a binary classification task based on some model, however, I was wondering how to do this in the absence of a model? For example, where we already **know the correct clusters** for each item.

We could manually measure the difference for each feature in each of the classes, but is there a more formal method of *ranking their influence*? Is feature ranking even the best approach here?

The overall question I aim to answer is: "What features are most important for deciding whether an item falls into (known) class A as opposed to (known) class b?"

Comment: Uhm, the question does not make sense... how does this situation *differ* from feature ranking for binary classification? Your "correct clusters" are the same thing as classes.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I may be wrong, but to do feature ranking, do you not have to do classification first and then measure 'how good' each feature was for the classification task? If so, in our case, we do not do classification first (i.e. have a model), as we already know the classes

Comment: In classification, you have training data (i.e. have a model)?